# CSS regexes besides ^,$,*

Tags: css

I know you can do things like

```
a[href^="http"]{...}
a[data-test*="test"]{...}
a[href$=".com"]{...}
```

but can you use any other more complex regexes in CSS/3 (not with a framework like less or sass) besides ^,$, and *?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: No - http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings

Comment: I'd advise using even the ones that are available only sparingly. Anything like this is going to have a performance hit: Put a handful of poorly thought out expressions into the CSS for a complex page and you can expect to see a noticable delay in your page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, all CSS level 1, 2 and 3 selectors are documented within the [Selectors Level 3 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors). A list of all these can be found in [Section 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) of this document.

Selectors which make use of square braces `[]` are known as Attribute Selectors ([Section 6.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)). The ones we're interested here are further grouped into two types:

### Attribute presence and value selectors ([6.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation))

These were introduced in CSS2:

> **[att]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.
>
> **[att=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".
>
> **[att~=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.
>
> **[att|=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-" (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow language subcode matches (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a element in HTML) as described in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor. For lang (or xml:lang) language subcode matching, please see the :lang pseudo-class.

### Substring matching attribute selectors ([6.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings))

These were introduced in CSS3:

> **[att^=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.
>
> **[att$=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.
>
> **[att*=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

The [Selectors Level 4 W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4) extends the `[att=val]` selector by allowing for case-insensitivity: [`[att=val i]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case). However no further attribute selectors have been added so far.

To answer your question: no, there are no additional substring matching attribute selectors other than `[att^=val]`, `[att$=val]` and `[att*=val]`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately (fortunately?) it doesn't have full support of regex. The ones you're missing are `[attr~=val]` and `[attr|=val]`. Here are all the attribute selectors with descriptions:

```
/* if attr exists */
a[attr]

/* if attr equals val */
a[attr=val]

/* attr is a whitespace-separated list where val is one of the values */
a[attr~=val]

/* attr's value is val followed by '-' (designed for culture codes) */
a[attr|=val]

/* attr starts with val */
a[attr^=val]

/* attr ends with val */
a[attr$=val]

/* attr contains val */
a[attr*=val]
```

I wrote an article on [my blog](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/11/advanced-css-selectors.html) with some decent examples for each selector if you're interested.